# Flutter in VSCode Interpreting package as URI

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-test

I'm trying to get started using flutter from VSCode. 
I think I've done all the proper setup:

1) Downloaded extensions for flutter and dart and codeRunner on VS code

2) Downloaded the flutter SDK and added it the path

3) Run flutter doctor with no doctor with no errors
[image]

After all the setup I tried clicking "Run Code", and received the error: **'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command**. After reading other online posts, I figured it was because I only added flutter SDK to my path and not dart SDK, so I added dart SDK to my path as well.

From there, I tried running the code again and got the following error:

```
lib/main.dart: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:tranfer_app/main.dart'.
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/chip_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
```

From my readings online, it sounds like VS Code might be trying to run as a dart app rather than a flutter app, and although I've found how to change this in Android Studio, I'm not sure how to change it in VSCode (which is where I'd like to do my development). Notably, if instead of running code with Ctrl+Alt+N, I use F5, the app will run just fine on an emulator, but I'd rather figure out these warnings before continuing as they seem important.

I expect my code to be runnable using the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> Code Runner.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Do you have the Flutter extension on VS Code?

Comment: Yes, flutter, dart, and CodeRunner

Comment: I would try reinstalling everything from scratch. It will probably be faster than trying to find what can be culprit of the conflict. It's a 5 minutes process on average.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I expect my code to be runnable using the usual Ctrl+Alt+N Code Runner.

Code Runner doesn't understand what Flutter is (or how to run it), so pressing this key combination will just run the Dart script in the VM. The warnings are because `dart:ui` is not available in the standalone VM (only via Flutter).

Using <kbd>F5</kbd> (or the Debug menu) is the correct way to run a Flutter app, as it will be handled by the Dart/Flutter extensions that automatically detect which tool to run the app with (as well as provide lots of other functionality like hot-reload-on-save).

If there's a reason running with <kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't work for you, I'd be interested in understanding why (you can file issues [on GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code)). Thanks!

Comment: Disabling coderunner worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, quite simple solution, basically you've been running the app as a separate package as the error says, and you should be running it as a flutter app.
So, simply run with or without debugging mode instead of using code runner as shown :

Note: This happened when I created more than one dart file in the lib.

Image:
[Use the run with/without debugging option and you should be good to go :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ldP.png)

Answer (score 0):

There could possibly be one more reason. If you've only lib folder or any other sub-folder open instead of whole package, you'd get this error. Try opening the whole folder -- the folder your lib folder is in.
Solved the error for me

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I accidentally deleted the pubspec.yaml file, please check it.